# How to read the predicted label of a Neural Network with Cross Entropy Loss?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, prediction, multilabel-classification

I am using a neural network to predict the quality of the Red Wine dataset, available on UCI machine Learning, using Pytorch, and Cross-Entropy Loss as the loss function.

This is my code:

```
input_size = len(input_columns)
hidden_size = 12
output_size = 6 #because there are 6 classes

#Loss function
loss_fn = F.cross_entropy

class WineQuality(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # input to hidden layer
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        # hidden layer and output
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        
    def forward(self, xb): 
        out = self.linear1(xb)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.linear2(out)
        return out
    
    def training_step(self, batch):
        inputs, targets = batch 
        # Generate predictions
        out = self(inputs) 
        # Calcuate loss
        loss = loss_fn(out,torch.argmax(targets, dim=1))
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch):
        inputs, targets = batch
        # Generate predictions
        out = self(inputs)
        # Calculate loss
        loss = loss_fn(out, torch.argmax(targets, dim=1))
        return {'val_loss': loss.detach()}
        
    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()   # Combine losses
        return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item()}
    
    def epoch_end(self, epoch, result, num_epochs):
        # Print result every 100th epoch
        if (epoch+1) % 100 == 0 or epoch == num_epochs-1:
            print("Epoch [{}], val_loss: {:.4f}".format(epoch+1, result['val_loss']))

model = WineQuality()

def evaluate(model, val_loader):
    outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in val_loader]
    return model.validation_epoch_end(outputs)

def fit(epochs, lr, model, train_loader, val_loader, opt_func=torch.optim.SGD):
    history = []
    optimizer = opt_func(model.parameters(), lr)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Training Phase 
        for batch in train_loader:
            loss = model.training_step(batch)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Validation phase
        result = evaluate(model, val_loader)
        model.epoch_end(epoch, result, epochs)
        history.append(result)
    return history

loss_value = evaluate(model, valid_dl)

#model=WineQuality()
epochs = 1000
lr = 1e-5
history = fit(epochs, lr, model, train_loader, val_loader)
```

I can see that the model is good and that the loss decreases. The problem is when I have to do a prediction on an example:

```
def predict_single(input, target, model):
    inputs = input.unsqueeze(0)
    predictions = model(inputs)
    prediction = predictions[0].detach()
    print("Input:", input)
    print("Target:", target)
    print("Prediction:", prediction)
    return prediction

input, target = val_df[1]
prediction = predict_single(input, target, model)
```

This returns:

```
Input: tensor([0.8705, 0.3900, 2.1000, 0.0650, 4.1206, 3.3000, 0.5300, 0.2610])
Target: tensor([6.])
Prediction: tensor([ 3.6465,  0.2800, -0.4561, -1.6733, -0.6519, -0.1650])
```

I want to see what are associated these logits, in the sense that I know that the highest logit is associated with the predicted class, but I want to see that class. I also applied softmax to rescale these values in a probability:

```
prediction = F.softmax(prediction)
print(prediction)
output = model(input.unsqueeze(0))
_,pred = output.max(1)
print(pred)
```

And the output is the following:

```
tensor([0.3296, 0.1361, 0.1339, 0.1324, 0.1335, 0.1346])
tensor([0])
```

I don't know what is that tensor([0]). I expect my predicted label, a value like 6.1 if the target is 6. But I am not able to obtain this.

Comment: You should use `argmax` after applying softmax.

Comment: @Frightera yes I did, but I receive always tensor([0]), instead my classes goes from 3 to 8

Comment: It might just be that your model is always predicting class `0`. Is your model properly trained? Is your dataset balanced?

Comment: Yes like Ivan says the max function is working properly. The softmax function just computes the probabilities that it is each class and then the max function sees which probability is the highest and outputs that class as the prediction of your model. Is your model properly trained?

Comment: @Ivan i think that my model is trained properly... i have a loss of 0.1

Comment: My dataset is unbalanced. Here there is the notebook already ran https://jovian.ai/casella0798/problem-with-classes

Comment: In your notebook, you only print a single prediction, have you trying predicting other datapoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Lets review the way you are calculating loss. From your code:

```
loss = loss_fn(out,torch.argmax(targets, dim=1))
```

you are using `torch.argmax` function which expects `targets` size as `torch.Size([num_samples, num_classes])` or `torch.Size([32, 6])` in your case. Are you sure your training labels are compatible with this size? From your writing I understand that you are reading label class as a number (from 3 to 8). So, its size is `torch.Size([32, 1])`. So, when you are calling `torch.argmax` with training data, `torch.argmax' is always returning 0.

**That's why the model is learning to predict the class 0 whatever the input is.**

Now, as your class label (for training) is from 3 to 8. Unfortunately if we use these labels with your `loss_fn` or `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`, it will be matched with total 9 labels, (class0 to class8) as maximum class labels is 8. So, you need to transform 3 to 8 -> 0 to 5. For loss calculation use:

```
loss = loss_fn(out, targets - 3)
```